# Get the uiview that is at the location of a touch

Tags: ios, xcode, uiview, uitouch

Is there a way to quickly get what views are are at (contain) the specific point of a UITouch? I have the coordinates relative to self.view but would like to know any/all of the views that are at that point. My view hierarchy is similar to

- self.view

  - scrollview

    - view
    - view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `CGRectContainsPoint()`  method.
This method will return a boolean value.
You need to pass the views frame(`CGRect`) and the coordinates relative to touch(`CGPoint`).

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGGeometry/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGRectContainsPoint

Also you can check with this method too,

```
CGPoint aPoint = //your touch point;
BOOL isPointInsideView = [yourView pointInside:aPoint withEvent:nil];
```

Here the given point (`aPoint`) is checked with the view you are giving (`yourView`) and returns a boolean value.

Comment: thanks, these both look good. I also found some info on hitTest: that might work too.